# HTML tags in comments using API

Tags: podio

I am creating a plugin for my PHP project. Which creates/updates items and comments in Podio. My PHP application stores comment on an item and sometimes it contains HTML tags as I read these comments from mails. But in my Podio item, these HTML tags are not rendering correctly and are showing as a string. Does comments support HTML tags? Please provide me a way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Podio will not support HTML in its items comment section.
Meanwhile, you can use Rich text(**MarkDown**) there.
Please refer [this link](http://www.globiflow.com/blog/markdown-rich-text-in-podio.php) for more info about Rich text formatting.

Comment: Small note: it's markdown editing that it's supported in comments, but apart from that you're correct.